# The diagonal functor, but 'one level up'. Useful to show functoriality of the limit functor?

Tags: category-theory, functors, complete-categories

Given some index category $\mathcal{I}$ and a complete category $\mathcal{C}$, we consider the diagonal functor $\Delta : \mathcal{C} \to [\mathcal{I}, \mathcal{C}]$ to be the functor that sends all objects $C$ of $\mathcal{C}$ to the constant diagram $\Delta(C)$ that maps each $I$ to the fixed object $C$? In particular, I want to show that the assignment that maps each diagram $D$ to its apex $X_D$ of its limit cone is itself a functor, say, '$\text{lim} : [\mathcal{I}, \mathcal{C}] \to \mathcal{C}$'. (Remember that we take our category $\mathcal{C}$ to be complete, or at least, to have all limits of shape $\mathcal{I}$.) In doing so, I first got confused, but then that confusion led to a possible insight. The confusion arose when I considered the action of $\Delta$ on morphisms (which in our case happen to be natural transformations $\mu : D \Rightarrow D'$). I wrote down $\Delta_{\mu}$, but soon realised that things were not well-defined. Then I came up with the idea to consider the diagonal functor 'one level up', in the following sense: $\Delta^\top : [\mathcal{I}, \mathcal{C}] \to [\mathcal{I}, [\mathcal{I}, \mathcal{C}]]$. I hoped this would prove useful to avoid lengthy verifications for showing functoriality (i.e., preservation of identities and morphisms) of 'lim', so I hoped that using this 'new' diagonal functor ($\Delta^\top$), of which we know that it is both itself a functor, but so are its images on the objects of $[\mathcal{I}, \mathcal{C}]$. Would this indeed be useful or just replace tedious verifications of functoriality of lim on morphisms to tedious verifications of well-definedness of $\Delta^\top$ on objects?

Concretely, can I define the morphism part of lim in terms of $\Delta^\top$ in such a way that I need not spell out the universal property of the terminal cone?

(Note: I need a very 'entry-level' proof, i.e., absent notions of Yoneda or adjunctions.)

Comment: Don't you want to domain of $\Delta$ to be $\mathcal{C}$? And what do you mean by "would it be equivalent to consider..."? There are not two things mentioned that can be equivalent to another. You just write down one functor. And what do you mean by "its vertex", do you mean the limit object? Is your question about defining the action of $\Delta$ on morphisms? This is trivial. If $c \to d$ is a morphism in $\mathcal{C}$, there is only one way to define a natural transformation $\Delta(c) \to \Delta(d)$. It has $c \to d$ in every component (what else?). Or what is your question?

Comment: I've made some adjustments, did they clarify my thought process?

Comment: Ah, I meant 'apex' instead of vertex, of course.

Comment: No, I fear this just makes things needlessly complicated. It felt like a useful path to pursue though, as the image of a natural transformation under the diagonal functor could essentially be considered 'a singleton'.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\C}{\mathsf{C}}$$\Delta$'s action on morphisms does not go for $\Delta(\mu)$ where $\mu$ is a natural transformation. $\Delta$ has domain $\C$ so the relevant morphisms are arrows within $\C$. As commented, there is only one obvious way that works in general to define $\Delta(f)$ for some $f:\varsigma\to\varsigma'$ in $\C$; it is to let it be the natural transformation with every component equal to $f$, $\Delta(\varsigma)\implies\Delta(\varsigma')$.

Things *are* well-defined here. You probably encountered issues because you mixed up the domain with the codomain; $\Delta(\mu)$ does not make sense. It is the $\lim$ functor which has to act on natural transformations and map these to arrows in $\C$, not $\Delta$ itself. The preservation of identities and composition by $\lim$ is quite easy to show and does not require lengthy verification. Use your universal properties (I'll elaborate on that if requested).

$\Delta$ and $\Delta^{\top}$ are both well-defined and this requires no verification at all; it is certainly not tedious. I really think you've just conflated the domain of $\Delta$ with that of $\lim$ and have become confused because of it.